# Using MvcGrid.Net error on binding filters MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, mvcgrid.net

I`m using MvcGrid.Net

Here is my **cshtml** page

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Opprtunity ID" data-mvcgrid-type="filter" data-mvcgrid-option="opprtunityid" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Cluster" data-mvcgrid-type="filter" data-mvcgrid-option="Cluster" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-mvcgrid-apply-filter="click">Apply</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have two simple search button. When I can try to bind them to the MVC grid confing file i can't see the value in the `QueryOptions`.

Here is my grid-options:

```
.WithRetrieveDataMethod((context) =>
     {
         var options = context.QueryOptions;
         int totalRecords;
         var repo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<General>();
         string sortColumn = options.GetSortColumnData<string>();
         var items = repo.GetData(out totalRecords,
                        options.GetFilterString("opprtunityid"),
                        options.GetFilterString("Cluster"),
                        //active,
                        options.GetLimitOffset(),
                        options.GetLimitRowcount(),
                        sortColumn, options.SortDirection == SortDirection.Dsc);
         return new QueryResult<SourcedPartner>()
         {
             Items = items,
             TotalRecords = totalRecords
         }
```

**options.GetFilterString("opprtunityid")** here i have a `null` value.

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 1):

When using MVCGrid.Net, you have to make sure that you set up the table definition in MVCGridConfig.cs .

Key elements to filtering are:

1) When declaring the column, you **must** make sure that you add the following code to the column definition -

```
.AddColumns(cols => {
     cols.Add("opportunityid").WithVisibility(false)
         .WithFiltering(true)      // MUST have filtering enabled on column definion, otherwise it will not appear in QueryOptions
         .WithValueExpression(i => i.OpportunityID);
     cols.Add("Cluster").WithHeaderText("Cluster")
         .WithFiltering(true)
         .WithVisibility(false)
         .WithAllowChangeVisibility(true)
         .WithValueExpression(i => i.Cluster);
```

2) You **must** make sure to include filtering as part of your MVCGridBuilder construction -

```
MVCGridDefinitionTable.Add("Filtered", new MVCGridBuilder<SourcedPartner>()
      .AddColumns(....)
      .WithSorting(true, "MySortedColumnName")
      .WithFiltering(true) // This lets the GridContext know that something will populate QueryOptions.Filters section
      .WithRetrieveDataMethod((context) => 
          {
             var options = context.QueryOptions;
             string opID = options.GetFilterString("opprtunityid");
             string cluster = options.GetFilterString("Cluster");
             .......
            });
```

When you debug your code, the Filters portion of QueryOptions will be populated with your values from the input boxes.  If there is no value, you will have a zero length string that you must check for.

The column needs to have filtering enabled.  The builder must have filtering enabled.  The column name must match the data-mvcgrid-option name.

When all of these things are set up, you should see the value from your inputs in the Filter section of the QueryOptions.

Know this is late, hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Look in the URL to see what variable/s are being sent and set accordingly in `options.GetFilterString(******).`

Worked for me.